# SQL entries not showing in graph

Tags: sql, date, graph, between

For a school project I am trying to produce a graph that shows me all the entries between two dates from  an SQL table. I am using the following code:

```
int bLost = 0;

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String strstartDate = sdf.format(startDate.getDate());
String strendDate = sdf.format(endDate.getDate());

try {   

    conn = JavaConnect.ConnecrDb();

    pst = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM lost"
                + " WHERE Datecreated >= " + strstartDate 
                + " AND Datecreated <=" + strendDate );

    rsLost = pst.executeQuery();

    if (rsLost.next()) {
        bLost = rsLost.getInt(1);
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Table cannot be found");
}

// this is some stuff for the graph
DefaultCategoryDataset bagStats = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

// This should show me how many entries it found 
bagStats.setValue(bLost, "Bagage Lost", "Bagage Lost");
```

The code works fine if i do the statement without the date part like this:

```
pst = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM lost"
```

I also tried using BETWEEN statements and it didn't work either.

I'm all out of ideas, I would really appreciate any help!

Caspar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put quotes around the string in your sql code, so it reads as follows:

```
pst = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM lost"
            + " WHERE Datecreated >= \'" + strstartDate 
            + "\' AND Datecreated <=\'" + strendDate + "\'");
```

Whenever constructing sql statements, it is a good idea to print the string statement on the command line or in a message box while debugging, so you can see exactly what is being passed.

Also, if accepting user input into a variable, it is good practice to parameterize the query in order to avoid the possibility of sql injection attacks.

Comment: hey thanks for your reply but the code you gave me gives me a syntax error in Netbeans. Besides it should be working without those quotes as it does in other classes i have

Comment: I've just made a couple of corrections, try it now.

Comment: It works! thank you so much, you just helped me with a problem i spent hours on!